# Separate reactive element for table header and table body

Tags: r, shiny

In Shiny / R, I would like to update table body and table header independently. Consider this example:

```
library( shiny )
tt <- read.table( text="  id      blah       foo
1  1      adsf foo1
2  2      ioiu foo2
3  3 ioiuoiuer foo3", stringsAsFactors= F ) 

runApp( list( 
  ui= basicPage( 
    tags$table(
      uiOutput( "myheader" ),
      uiOutput( "mybody" )

    )

  ),

  server= function( input, output ) { 

    output$myheader <- renderUI({
      tags$thead(
        tags$tr( lapply( colnames( tt ), function( x ) tags$th( x ) ) )
      )

    })

    output$mybody <- renderUI({
      rows <- list()
      for( i in 1:nrow( tt ) ) {
        rows[[i]] <- tags$tr( lapply( tt[i,], function( x ) tags$td( x ) ) )
      }

      tags$tbody( rows )
    })
  } ) )
```

In *theory*, I am creating separately the body and header elements of the table. However, the way the shiny is rendering the page, both elements end up *outside* of the table:

[image]

**Is it possible (and if yes, then how) to update the table header and body separately in Shiny?**

Short explanation why I'm not using the default xtable or dataTable: I have a very large data frame in R, so I don't want to use dataTable. Filtering, searching, sorting and paging should all be done on the server side. However, as I want to have all these nice gimmicks, I need to re-implement data frame to HTML table conversion. I run into a problem with radio buttons in the table header -- when the table is redisplayed, the buttons are reset and trigger another event. The easiest solution (also, more elegant) would be to render the table body separately from the table head.

Comment: FYI, the `dataTableOutput` that comes with Shiny 0.8.0 does filtering, searching, sorting, and paging on the server side.

Comment: @JoeCheng I didn't know that! Thank you. But the filtering is done only on the current page -- am I wrong? At least that is what I see.

Comment: @January Filtering is done for the whole dataset, not only the current page.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There is, however, another reason for not using dataTable: I want the numbers to be nicely formatted, i.e. certain values in grey, others in bold; small values in scientific notation, others not. I cannot do it a priori -- mixing scientific notation and "regular" numbers and storing them as character vectors will mess up the sorting. I probably could create a hack on the client side, but R is just so much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why this happens in your code. However, the code chunk below produces a table as you expect. Would this work for your application?

```
myheader <- reactive({
  tags$thead(
    tags$tr( lapply( colnames( tt ), function( x ) tags$th( x ) ) )
  )
})


mybody <- reactive({
  rows <- list()
  for( i in 1:nrow( tt ) ) {
    rows[[i]] <- tags$tr( lapply( tt[i,], function( x ) tags$td( x ) ) )
  }

  tags$tbody( rows )
})

output$mytable <- renderUI({
    tags$table(
      myheader(),
      mybody()
    )
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no (this is how I currently do it). Although the header is not directly generated again on the server side, the whole table is, and it gets sent to the client including header (you can see it with `options( shiny.trace= T )`). This causes an update of the buttons that I have in the header, and triggers a change of the button values.

Comment: Too bad. Can you show some more code? Perhaps there is another workaround. Also, you might consider posting this as an issue on github. What version of Shiny are you using? I am using .8.0.99. Does this happen in .80 as well?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that this is not the intended behavior. Anyway, I have solved the issue with a workaround, without buttons in the table header.